# How to get the id of the row in onItemClick(ListView) when using a custom Adapter?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I was searching for a while but i couldn't  find the solution.

Situation:

I'm using a `ListView` and I have in a `Cursor` the result of a SQLiteDatabase.query.

1. If I use a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, when
   you call `onItemClick(AdapterView<?>
   parent, View view, int position,
   long id)`, the `id` returned is the `_id`
   of the row of the given Cursor
2. but if I use a custom Adapter the
   return id works like an array
   [0,1,2,3], how can I set in the
   custom Adapter this id?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adapter has a method that you can override, called `getItemId(int pos)`.
Just return whatever id you need for a given item position and it will be passed to you on the item click.

Comment: thanks, Looks like is what i was looking for, is returning the correct id.