# How to override the getItemId(int pos) method from CursorAdapter?

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I am getting this question due to another answer on here, but didn't explain how to do what I am asking 
[How to get the id of the row in onItemClick(ListView) when using a custom Adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826683/how-to-get-the-id-of-the-row-in-onitemclicklistview-when-using-a-custom-adapte)

The answer which was accepted in that question is what I need since I am also making my own custom adapter (CursorAdapter), hence I will have the same problem. The problem is I have no idea how to accomplish that. I am looking at the Doc, and am not sure how to access the _id column from a cursor. Since the Doc doesn't have the constant which we can get that info from I'm stuck. Any help figuring it out would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I was not clear on what my question was, but just to clarify, like the title, how can I override the getItemId() method in the CursorAdapter custom class I created?

Comment: I don't understand your issue... I have several custom cursor adapters, I've never had to override that and I get the row id from the cursor just fine... What are you trying to do and where are you trying to get that id?

Comment: When I click a member from the list view, I want to be able to go into the database and use that ID to access that members information. So I need to make sure I actually get the _id. But I am not.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing why not... you should be if you are using `onListItemClick` with your list.

Comment: By default, should it be doing that? Like making the list id the _id from the database?

Comment: Yes.  Hence my original question about what you were trying to do and where you were trying to do it.  :)  If you use an `onListItemClick` method, the `int pos` part is the adapter position (0 to count-1) and `long id` is the row column id from the database (whatver that many be).

Comment: I must of done something wrong then. Thanks a lot for your input. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you don't have the Cursor as a member of your Adapter:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    Cursor cursor = getCursor();
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    return cursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
}
```

Comment: Ahh, so calling getCursor gets the associated cursor that the CursorAdapter is using? Should have realized that!! Thanks

Comment: Yes, here's a reference for [getCursor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#getCursor%28%29)

Comment: And If you are using CursorAdapter and not SimpleCursorAdapter then you should set the position in newView like this ` @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        holder.deleteImageView = (ImageView) retView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        holder.deleteImageView.setTag(cursor.getPosition());
        return retView;
    }

`

Answer (score 4):

I  nkow this doesn't answer the question posed, but Sam took care of that.  I thought I'd post this because there seems to be some confusion on the OPs part.

Following is an `onListItemClick` method from an activity that contains a list created with a custom cursor adapter:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Your code here
}
```

`long id` is the row id for the data contained in the row clicked (when the list is fed by a cursor adapter).  No need to override `getItemId`.

You only need to override the `getItemId` (in my experience) if you do something like put information from different rows into a single line.  As long as all your data for a list line is from the same row in the database, there's no need to go to that trouble.

I suppose another time you may need to use it would be if you took data from a cursor and put it into an array and then used an array adapter.. but that seems pretty roundabout...

Comment: Well it is the row _id that I want, at least from the database. But I see what you are saying

Comment: That **is** the row id (or _id if you prefer to think of it in terms of the database column name).  That is why a colum called `_id` is *required* in any cursor feeding an adapter... the framework uses it and passes it along so you can use it when you click on a line.