# Android - Using getItemID in an ArrayListAdapter

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I have scoured SO and the net looking for a solution to my problem.

I am trying to replace a SimpleCursorAdapter with an ArrayListAdapter.

I have successfully created my Adapter class and now need to access the _id value of the array in order to complete some required processing.

I found this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891272/how-to-override-the-getitemidint-pos-method-from-cursoradapter) that I think will solve my problem but I am getting an error stating that getCursor() is undefined in my adapter.

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
Cursor cursor = getCursor();
cursor.moveToPosition(position);
return cursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
```

}

There is no cursor in my adapter so I am confused...the ArrayList Adapter works fine as implemented.  Note, however, that when I add the _id field as a member of my Adapter class, only 0 is displayed in the field, yet all other field data is accurate. If I query my database directly, I receive all fields expected and all are accurate.

How do I access the cursor?  And, how do I access the _id value?

Any assistance will be most appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)?

Comment: Yes, sorry that is what I should have typed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter` and `SimpleCursorAdapter` are two different things and work in two different ways.

A `Cursor` is used to read data from a SQLite database and `SimpleCursorAdapter` is used to read the data from this cursor, but an `ArrayAdapter` will work with a `List` or an array.

So, as you can understand, you don't have a `Cursor` in an `ArrayAdapter` but only a `List`/Array (only the data!).

In an `ArrayAdapter` a `getItemId` is implemented by return `position` since it's the unique position in the List/Array.

Comment: I do understand the difference; the problem remains that I am unable to access the _id value using the ArrayAdapter.  If I use adapter.getItemId(position), I get incorrect results.

Comment: No, here your _id will be the position passed. The _id is a field in the database (which you don't have) and here who contains the data is the internal list/array.

Comment: Ok, so that is my problem...I need the primary key of the record and will need to include it in my adapter class somehow.  Thanks!